# Request.Cookies not set as expected

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I am rewriting an ASP classic (ASPC) application in ASP.NET/C# (ASPX).  One of the changes
I found was in a setting up a query using a value from the Request.Cookies collection:

```
sSQL = "select..." & " where S = '" & Request.Cookies("K")("S") & "'"
```

In ASPC the Request cookie is set and a record is returned from the DB.

In ASPX, the Request cookie is not set and the query returns no record.

The original logic sets the value in the Response.Cookies from the query string:

```
    if  Request.QueryString("K") <> "" then 
        Response.Cookies("K")("S") = Request.QueryString("S")
    end if
```

I find that Request.Cookies is not set explicitly anywhere in the original ASPC code.

For now, my  fix was to add a statement to set the Request Cookie:

```
    if  Request.QueryString("K") <> "" then 
        Response.Cookies("K")("S") = Request.QueryString("S")
        Request.Cookies("K")("S") = Request.QueryString("S") ' adding this fixes the issue, but its a kludge
    end if
```

But, I do not understand why this addition was needed.

It seems there is a difference in how Request.Cookies and Response.Cookies values
are maintained by ASPC and ASPX.  Has anyone else seen this?  Is this a known
difference in ASPC and ASPX?

This is happening in IIS7, IE11 (and firefox), using C#4.5, VS2015.

Answer (score 0):

After looking more closely at the issue I found the problem only manifests with a multi-value Cookie.  It appears I was running into a problem with propagating multi-value cookies.  The specific scenario was that page1 does a form-post to  page2 then page2 does some work and does a redirect back to page1.  I found the Cookies were not initialized in page2.

The problem did not occur for simple cookies.  I solved this by changing the multi-value cookies to simple cookies:

```
Response.Cookies["Key"].Values["SubKey"]
to 
Response.Cookies["Key-SubKey"].Value
```

In my case, the use of multi-value cookies seemed pretty arbitrary. (sometimes its hard to tell why someone did what they did when you inherit code) IMO this change is just a different way to do the same thing so its a refactoring -- possibly even simplification.

Other possible solutions might be possible by reworking the code.  I am curious about the underlying assumptions for multi-value cookies in ASPX to understand why the value was lost.